# content only appears if print is called twice javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm currently trying be able to print something to the screen using javascript. Right now, I've got a simple print function set up like below that gets triggered on a link press in HTML.

```
   function print() {
        console.log(printImgURL);
        let w = window.open();
        w.document.write(`<img src="${printImgURL}">`);
        w.focus();
        w.print();
        w.close();
    }
```

```
<a id="printButton" onclick="print()"title="Print"></a>
```

The content only appears when the link is pressed the second time (and any other time after), Although the console.log statement shows the proper URL to the image regardless if the image actually appears in the print dialogue or not. Does anyone have any idea why the content wouldn't be showing up the first the link is pressed?

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `printImgURL` and `printIMG`? Also why do you use unsafe inline `on*` attributes and `document.write` instead of i.e: `.append()`?

Comment: sorry, printImgURL and printIMG are actually the same thing, I forgot to rename them when bringing the code over to stack overflow. Additionally if using .append(), I get this error: index.js:138 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'append' on 'Document': Nodes of type '#text' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document'.

Answer (score -1):

Add `href="#"` in the anchor tag.

Example:

```
<a id="printButton" onclick="print()" title="Print" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, any other ideas?